# Visual Studio 2017 not opening

Tags: visual-studio-2017

This morning, I made a change to my machine.config file (just changed one of the membershipprovider properties), and I closed out of running VS2017 as Admin, but when I went to open it back up to go back to my solution, it wouldn't open. It will show the splash, the splash will go away, and then nothing will happen. I tried restarting the computer. I also tried opening from the command line using the /SafeMode switch. Also tried running a few other switches, and nothing works. The /Log switch left the splash up longer than anything else, but still didn't open VS. It is Visual Studio 2017 Community, if that makes a difference.

I have referenced [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/742762/microsoft-visual-studio-2013-wont-load-past-splash-screen), but I didn't make a hardware change, and that's where I got the idea to try to run from command prompt with safe mode switch and also tried the reset settings switch.

Comment: Never got an answer for this, but one thing I did find is that using InstallCleanup from the command line is a bad idea. Had to re-install OS in order to use VS2017 or SQL Server again.